# saving a veriable in a while loop for later use

Tags: java, while-loop

I cannot seem to find the answer anywere, albiet the fact that i am very new to java and are probably looking for the wrong thing.

```
       public class ClassMethodtest {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner replay = new Scanner(System.in);

    String answer;



   do{ 
      MoveClass newMoveClass = new MoveClass();

     newMoveClass.MoveAround();

     newMoveClass.Location();

            System.out.println("move again?");

    answer = replay.next();


   } while(answer.equals("yes"));
}




public class MoveClass {

private final String array[] = {"A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", 
                         "C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "D1", "D2", "D3", "D4"};
private final Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);    

private String location = array[0]; 


public void MoveAround(){

    System.out.println("move around");
    String answer = kb.next();

   switch (location) {
       case "A1":
           if(answer.equals("down")){
               location = array[4];
           }
           else if(answer.equals("right")){
               location = array[1];
           }  break;
           //etc.....
```

how do i do it so each time the loop is run that it 'saves' the result for the next time the loop runs? as it reverts back to the first decleration of 'location' when the while loop in the main class is looped again.

Comment: Your code example will not do what you claim it will. Please try and produce an example that actually shows the problem you are having. In this example, `x` will be `1` until the loop starts, then `2` for the duration of the loop.

Comment: Also explain what you really mean by "when the loop restarts". A main method is run only once. Why would the loop ever restart?

Comment: What do you mean by "when the loop restarts?" While it stays in the loop? Please be more clear about your question

Comment: @Lattyware actually, the code won't even compile because x is declared twice.

Comment: @JBNizet Well, and `something` doesn't exist - I was overlooking these issues. This example really doesn't help. My guess is that the user's actual problem is probably the use of `=` in while statement instead of `==`, and then miss-attributing it to something inside the loop. It's impossible to say for sure without a real code sample.

Comment: im sorry i only used that code as a concept of what i was trying to figure out, rather than the code itself, i am new not only to java, but stack overflow. i have put the actual code of what i want up now.

Comment: So you trying to move the same instance of moveClass around?

Comment: Okay, I'll edit my answer to consider that, but the problem is still that you are declaring the variable inside the scope of the do-while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are re-creating the `newMoveClass` object every time your code runs through the do-while. You need to modify your code a little so that the instance of MoveClass you created is the same for all the iterations of the loop, like this:

```
MoveClass newMoveClass = new MoveClass();

do{ 

     newMoveClass.MoveAround();

     newMoveClass.Location();

     System.out.println("move again?");

     answer = replay.next();


   } while(answer.equals("yes"));
```

A more general example might look something like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> results = new ArrayList<Integer>();

while(<some condition>) {
    // do computation with Integer temp
    Integer temp = new Integer(100);
    results.add(temp);
}
```

After the while loop condition no longer holds, you will have the results in the ArrayList.

Comment: This *might* be the answer, but it's so hard to tell what the user is asking, I would hold off until the user clarifies.

Comment: thank you so much, worked perfectly!!! it may not seem like much to expert coders but your answer has just opened many doors for me. thanks a bunch :)